Compute a inner product in $\ell^2$-
Let $V=\{v_n\}_n\subseteq \ell^2$ defined by $$v_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}e_k-\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}e_k\right)$$ where $e_i$ is an infinite vector of zeros except for the $i$ position, that is equal to one, for all $i$. Prove that $V$ is orthonormal.
First, I check that every vector is unitary.
$$\|v_n\|_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}1^2+\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}}1^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}\cdot\sqrt{2^{n+1}}=1$$
Then, for all $n<m$, I check the orthogonality:
$$\langle v_n,v_m \rangle=\langle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}e_k-\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}e_k\right), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{m+1}}}\left(\sum_{h=0}^{2^m-1}e_h-\sum_{h=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}e_h\right) \rangle=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{m+n+2}}}\langle\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}e_k-\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}e_k\right), \left(\sum_{h=0}^{2^m-1}e_h-\sum_{h=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}e_h\right) \rangle=$$
$$\overset{(\clubsuit)}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{m+n+2}}}\left(\langle \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} e_k,\sum_{h=0}^{2^m-1}e_h-\sum_{h=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}e_h\rangle - \langle \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} e_k,\sum_{h=0}^{2^m-1}e_h-\sum_{h=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}e_h\rangle\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{m+n+2}}}\left(\langle\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}e_k, \sum_{h=0}^{2^m-1}e_h\rangle-\langle\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1}e_k, \sum_{h=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}e_h\rangle-\langle\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}e_k, \sum_{h=0}^{2^m-1}e_h\rangle+\langle \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} e_k,\sum_{h=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}e_h \rangle\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{m+n+2}}}(2^n-2^n-2^n+2^n)=0$$
Is the use of bilinearity of the inner product in $(\clubsuit)$ right? Is the last step calculation right? I'm messing up with that calculation and I need an help!

Looks good to me.

Thank you very much! Can you explain me why all of the four final inner products are equal to $2^n$? The first and the second are clear, but the other two aren't clear to me.

Sorry, I've missed some coefficients. Since $n<m$, all $e_k$ in the second term are different than all $e_h$. Same thing happens in the last term. In the third term, the $h$ from $0$ to $2^n-1$ is not found in $k$, and same from $2^{n+1}$ to $2^{m}-1$. So your last parenthesis should be $(2^n-0-2^n+0)$.

Thank you very much!
